# Apply custom pagination in ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

I want to do customized pagination in my asp.net c# application. I don't want to use gridview's default pagination. Is there any plugin or package which has paginations links with limiters of page numbers like << 1 2 3 4 5 ... >>. If we click on >> button the links will be << 6 7 8 9 10 ... >>   and so on. I have done so many research on it but could not find any perfect solution for it. I request you to please help me!!!

Comment: i can give you simple idea... for example, you want to show 10 records, then on page 1, select 1 to 10 record from database, by selecting 2 you have to skip first 10 record and fetch next 10 records and so on

Comment: i m sorry, i m not getting you

Comment: my requirement is different...

Comment: you want customized pagination, am i right ?

Comment: `paginations links with limiters like << 1 2 3 4 5 ... >>. If we click on >> button the links will be << 6 7 8 9 10 ... >> ` so on clicking `>>` you wll be on last page normally, you want to change that ? like on clicking you should be on page `6` instead of last page ?

Comment: yes sir... I want that which has limiters otherwise the paginnation which I have already implemented has  page numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25... Now the issue is that it doesnot  look good displaying all the page numbers near grid view. So I want that it should display 1 to 5 numbers then if we click on >> it should display 6 to 10 and so on....

Answer (score 0):

inside property of gridview you can set pagger settings like `PageButtonCount`

try this

[image]